# DLL import based on operating system

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, missingmethodexception

I am trying to import an external DLL based on the users OSVersion.
Problem started by using the method [GetDpiForWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow) which requires Windows 10, version 1607. As this method is missing in older OS Versions like windows 7 an exception is thrown as soon as the class instance is initiated. Is it possible to implement a OSVersion check before the dll gets imported? In this special case also catch of the import exception would do the trick as I could return 96.

```
 public static class WindowUtil
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetDpiForWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static double GetWindowDPIFactor(IntPtr winhandle)
        {
            if (winhandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return (double)GetDpiForWindow(winhandle) / 96;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `thrown as soon as the class instance is initiated` - no, `DllImport` only loads the dll when the method is first called. So test your OS version before you call your method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle a failed DllImport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970017/how-do-i-handle-a-failed-dllimport)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562260/c-sharp-dllimport-of-non-existent-function

Comment: 96 would be a pretty bad fallback. Should be the system dpi I guess